# Update a record from remote database in Swift using URL with parameter

Tags: php, database, swift

I want to pass an integer parameter in a url to update a field for a record in remote database but I get errors. How can that be done? My php works but not if called from Swift. How do you execute a php file for updating a database record in Swift?

Below is the php on the server for updating record. How do I run this from a Swift app? From the web I do it this way and it runs (IdTask is unique):

http://.../updateonetasktocompleted.php?x=2

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //database host server
$db = "dbname"; //database name
$user = "dbuser"; //database user
$pass = "passwd"; //password

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if(!$connection)
{
die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
//Attempt to select the database
$dbconnect = mysql_select_db("dbname", $connection);

//Check to see if we could select the database
if(!$dbconnect)
{
    die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
}
else
{
    $idtask_selected = $_GET['x'];

    $query = "UPDATE ProtocolSets_Protocols SET `ProtocolSets_Protocols`.`Completed`='Yes' WHERE `ProtocolSets_Protocols`.`IdTask`= $idtask_selected";        

    $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

    echo "Successfully added ";
    echo $query;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Dude show your code here. And also what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run a command-line php script from your Swift code, you can use NSTask:

```
var task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/path/to/your/script/script.php"
task.arguments = ["25"]
task.launch()
```

But I may be misunderstanding your question, since you didn't provide a lot of context.

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't quite understand what you're asking.  Are you looking to port the php code to Swift, or simply call existing php code from swift code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to do it:

```
let currentIdTask:Int? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("selectedIdTask")?.toInt()

var url: NSString = "http://.../updateonetasktocompleted.php?x=\(currentIdTask!)"
url = url.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20")
url = url.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("/n", withString: "%0A")
println(url)

var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)
var result = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
println(result)
```